# A less sensitive serialization method

Tags: r, serialization

#### Background

The [`drake`](https://github.com/ropensci/drake) package is like Make for R-focused data science projects. It detects changes in dependencies to decide whether to build downstream targets. The dependencies farthest upstream are usually user-defined functions, [`R6`](https://github.com/r-lib/R6) classes, etc. To detect changes, [`drake`](https://github.com/ropensci/drake) relies on serialization and hashing.

#### The problem

For [`drake`](https://github.com/ropensci/drake)'s purposes, serialization is oversensitive when it comes to objects that contain functions. For example, when I call an [`R6`](https://github.com/r-lib/R6) method, the internals of the class change even though the class itself did not change in any meaningful way. As Winston Chang helpfully pointed out [here](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/345#issuecomment-377040874), `serialize()` overreacts to trivial record-keeping (visible with `.Internal(inspect())`).

```
library(digest)
library(R6)
some_class <- R6Class(
  "some_class",
  private = list(x = NULL),
  public = list(
    initialize = function(x) {
      private$x <- x
    }
  )
)
digest(some_class)
#> [1] "8ae94b2fe26264ca68eb39da640da5a1"
object <- some_class$new(123)
digest(some_class)
#> [1] "c4cc5a51c85cb2e4a773cf6e29684f7d"
object <- some_class$new(123)
digest(some_class)
#> [1] "f94260c269920b53db838d2fcf53271f"
object <- some_class$new(123)
digest(some_class)
#> [1] "f94260c269920b53db838d2fcf53271f"
object <- some_class$new(123)
```

#### Questions

1. Is there a way to exclude trivial internals from serialization and/or hashing?
2. If I need to implement a custom serialization method, what are some good resources for learning about serialization and the internals I need to access?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround solution you can wrap up the `R6` class definition inside a function:

No wrapping-up:

```
library(drake)
library(digest)
library(R6)
some_class <- R6Class(
  "some_class",
  private = list(x = NULL),
  public = list(
    initialize = function(x) {
      private$x <- x
    }
  )
)

plan <- drake_plan(
  new_obj = some_class$new(x = 10)
)
```

```
make(plan)
> target new_obj
make(plan)
> target new_obj
```

With the wrapping up:

```
new_object <- function(x) {
  some_class <- R6Class(
    "some_class",
    private = list(x = NULL),
    public = list(
      initialize = function(x) {
        private$x <- x
      }
    )
  )
  some_class$new(x = x)
}

plan <- drake_plan(
  new_obj = new_object(10)
)
```

```
make(plan)
> target new_obj
make(plan)
v All targets are already up to date.
```